# Different columns in recordsource change with vba do not update accordingly

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a subform which displays the results from a saved query.
Now I want to change to another query.

```
Me.SF_Results.Form.RecordSource = "NewQuery"
```

It works but the columns which were in the old query and are not in the new query are still displayed and show #Name? in every cell.

How can I update the columns for the new query?

I have found a solution here which involves setting the recordsource to an empty string and then to the new query, but it not working for me.
Also they use "Query.NewQuery" there for some to me unknown reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use `Query.NewQuery` for the `Source Object` not the `Record Source` because they are displaying a query in the subform control, not a form. The subform control is a container that can display tables and queries as well as forms. I would not suggest displaying an editable query, you will lose all control of your data. If you really must do this, make sure that the control is locked.

Alternatively, say something about your data and someone may be able to suggest a different solution.

Comment: You caught it, I confused SourceObject with RecordSource.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 subforms, in the same position on the main form, and just set `.Visible` approprately for whichever one you want them to view

```
Me.SF_Results.Form.Visible=False
Me.Other_SF_Results.Form.Visible=True
```

Comment: I do not think that this is the best option. You can fill a single subform control with forms as you need them, rather than having multiple subform controls. The form will load faster - sometimes much faster. Furthermore, the OP seems to require dynamic data, so you could need quite a few forms to cover all eventualities.